# Comparing objects in a conditional, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following code in my program that is used to append a setting to a list or if already in the list remove it. If the setting already has a value then it should be sent to self.commit_setting and if not then self.commit_setting is passed. Like wise for removing the setting except instead of committing the setting it undoes it.

```
    no_color = Gdk.RGBA(red=0.000000, green=0.000000, blue=0.000000, alpha=1.000000)

    if setting in self.setting_lst:
        self.setting_lst.remove(setting)  # if the setting is in the list remove it

        # NOTE: get_rgba() returns a Gdk.RGBA object
        if self.get_rgba() == no_color:  # if value not set then pass
            pass
        else:
            self.undo_setting()
    else:
        self.setting_lst.append(setting)  # add setting to list if not already in it
        if self.get_rgba() == no_color: # if value not set then pass
            pass
        else:
            self.commit_setting()
```

Currently this code is working fine for me but I would like to simplify it  by only using an if with out the else, implying that if the condition is not met it will always be else. I would like to put:

```
        if self.get_rgba() != no_color:
           self.commit_setting()
```

Unfortunately when I do this self.commit_setting() or undo_setting() is executed even if the color is equal to no_color. Why is this? does the "!" operator not work for comparing objects?

Comment: Does `if not (self.get_rgba() == no_color:)` work?  If not, try using `if not (self.get_rgba() is no_color:)`.

Comment: Also, can you check <>, which should directly call the __ne__() method wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming , `self.get_rgba()` and `no_color` return objects (instances) of the same class . You can have that class overwrite the `__eq__` function which is internally called when checking for equality and `__ne__` for not equality -

```
def __eq__(self, other): 
    return self.somethings = other.somethings
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

You can also just define one of these (you do not need to define both).

### EDIT:

Also , for before Python 3.0 , you can also also `__cmp__` function in a similar way, it should return -1 if `self` has less value , 1 if `self` has greater value and 0 if `self` is equal to `other` .

The above functions - `__eq__` or `__ne__` are called rich comparison operators , for a complete list you can check out - [rich comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: In this case, wouldn't it be an issue in the __ne__(self, other) method-wrapper, since ==  works and != does not??

Comment: Added that, I missed that.

Comment: @AnandSKumar  thanks for the informative comment I found that not (self.get_rgba() == no_color) gave me the result I was looking for though.

Comment: Keep in mind, that unless `__cmp__` or `__eq__` is overwritten , `==` would be comparing the address values for both objects , if that is what you want, then it should be good.

Answer (score 0):

As @James mentioned in his comment I can use `if not (self.get_rgba() == no_color):` to get it to work. It was easy to do and it did exactly what I was looking to do. But I am still wondering why "!=" would not work, Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: You can check the information in the above answer for answer to that, i am guessing you do not have __ne__ function overwritten.